# dynamic php page calls

Tags: php, html, database

So I have looked through many of the other questions posted but none seemed to properly answer my question.

I currently have a php script that reads rows from a database and runs a loop to display the info of each row in a html div.

The issue I am now having is that in each "card" of info previously loaded there has a picture. And when the picture is clicked I need to load a different file names listing.html. The problem is that depending on which picture is clicked on I want to load different information based on which listing was clicked on. I looked into using sessions but since i dynamically load all of the pictures in one loop I do not know a way to differentiate between them.

here is the code I currently have that loads all the info from the database.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Listings ORDER BY OrderNumber";

                        if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query))
                        {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
                            {
                            echo "<div class ='listing'>";
                            echo "<a href='listing.html'>";
                            echo "<img src=$row[2] alt='' width='60%' align='left' >";
                            echo "</a>";
                            echo "<span style = 'font-size: 25px;'>";
                            echo $row[4];
                            echo "</span>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "MLS Number: #";
                            echo $row[1];
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<b>Open House Details: </b>";
                            echo $row[6];
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo $row[5];
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "<a href='";
                            echo $row[9];
                            echo "' style='color: #8a0b0b; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-size: 18px;' target='_blank'>Virtual Tour</a>";
                            echo "<div class='listingPrice'>";
                            echo "$ ";
                            echo $row[7];
                            echo "</div>";
                            echo "</div>";

                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        }
```

I need some way that when the a tag is clicked to first be able to discern which picture was clicked then probably make a session variable with the corresponding row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you output the link, include a query string value from the row in the data.  Something like this:

```
echo "<a href='listing.html?id=" . row[0] . "'>";
```

(I'm just guessing on the `row[0]` part, it would be any identifier which uniquely identifies that record.)  That way all of the links would have the data you need on the `listing.html` page embedded directly in them.  (Shouldn't it be `listing.php`?)

So on the page being referenced, the value would then be available in the query string.  Something like this:

```
$_GET["id"]
```

There really isn't a need for session state in this case, if all you need to know is which record was clicked then that information can be placed directly in the link.  This reduces coupling in the code, keeps the links a little more RESTful, even lets people bookmark the link directly if they want to.